# Pro-grammatically create User/Guest accounts in android

Tags: android, sdk, android-source

I am trying to create User / Guest account in android pragmatically.

I have a JSON file defining number of user for an application.

When app initiates it creates/adds new user OR guest account to android device.

Once created, I want to get list of guest added and switch between account from app only i.e. when some one clicks on the user, account is switched like it switches when we do from system bar icons.

Can this be achieved through changes in AOSP as I have flexibility to deploy custom ROM.

I am not able to get any document over Developer site, which states how this can be achieved.

Comment: Not clear on the use case for creating user accounts (from a use case perspective). However have you looked at: [Android Enterprise Management](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview) also known as Mobile Device Management (MDM)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Use case is to impliment a custom launcher for self owned device where I could create set of user when launcher is launched.

Comment: Okay but why do you need multiple users? Perhaps [this](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/multiple-users) may be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Use [android.os.UserManager](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java#1457)  to create users